# Visual C++ Standard Library keywords

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, std

I wanted to write a unicode version of std::exception and std::runtime_error.
So I thought what better way then to just take implementations from the C++ Standard Library and alter them to support unicode.

So I pulled up the *exception* and *stdexcept* headers in Visual C++, copied the code, made my changes.

The thing is I couldn't get it to link unless I removed the `_CRTIMP_PURE`.
I also removed the `_EXCEPTION_INLINE __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL` prefix from all the member functions.

It's working but I'm very curious what all those things did.
`_EXCEPTION_INLINE` it literally defined right above it as `#define _EXCEPTION_INLINE`, and my googling skills can't find any documentation on what they do.

So, does anyone know what these are meant to do? And why it wound't link until I removed the `_CRTIMP_PURE` prefix from the class?

Comment: When you say 'unicode', I think what you actually mean is 'UTF-16', because `char*` and `std::string` are perfectly suitable for UTF-8, which is also unicode, and superior to UTF-16.

Comment: Did you at least rename `std::exception` and `std::runtime_error` after you copied and altered them? Having a hacked library class coexist with a compiler-supplied one seems like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley : Unicode has always been encoded as UTF-16 in Windows, so I think *Unicode* and *UTF-16* are used interchangeably in Microsoft land.

Comment: @EmileCormier Yeah, I renamed them to wexception and wruntime_error. There's not a lot of code, and when I took out the _CRTIMP_PURE everything worked fine.

Comment: @EmileCormier: I know that to some people, they are interchangeable, but those people are wrong, and need to be corrected.  And no, Unicode isn't always encoded in UTF-16 on Windows.  It depends upon what libraries you are interfacing with.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley : I meant the Windows API, but your point about Unicode / UTF16 not being fungible still stands. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't really anything mysterious (but it might be a bit pf a pain to track down where they're defined - but only a little). They're defined in headers that are part of the library, and they take on different definitions depending on how the compiler is configured for the current run. In particular, these macros seem to be concerned mostly with whether or not the current run is configured for `/clr:pure`.

`_CRTIMP_PURE` is defined to `__declspec(dllimport)` if you're linking against the DLL version of the C runtime (and not building with `/clr:pure`), and defined to nothing otherwise.

If your library isn't a DLL (or if it won't necessarily be a DLL whenever the DLL runtime is configured), then you shouldn't use it.  You probably shouldn't use it anyway, because you'd need to define it differently when *building* your library than when your library is being used (that's what Microsoft does when they build the C runtime libraries).

`__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL` is used by Microsoft's libraries to declare a function with `__clrcall` if you're building with `/clr:pure` (indicating these functions will only be called by managed code - the compiler can perform certain optimizations in that case it seems).

Finally, `_EXCEPTION_INLINE` is used to make the member functions of `class exception` `inline` if building with `/clr:pure`.

So the bottom line is, don't use `__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL` or `_EXCEPTION_INLINE` unless you plan to support `/clr` for your library, and you probably shouldn't use `_CRTIMP_PURE` in your implementation, but probably should use something similar of your own making and under your own control.

Answer (score 1):

Standard library implementation code often uses compiler-specific extensions for performance/documentation/reliability reasons. You should not use these extensions in your own code, because they can break in subsequent versions of the compiler.

There's no problem in duplicating the *interface* of `std::exception` and friends, and you can look at Visual Studio's implementation for inspiration. But your implementation should only use publically documented language/library features.